# Print/echo just one field with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, echo

I have the following code:

```
    echo "";
    print_r($facebook->api('/me?fields=email','GET'));
    echo "";
```

This provides the email & ID into an array.

How do you just print/echo the email field and not the ID field?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot request only `email`, just because FB api **always** returns used id additionally.

But you can just go with intermediate array for storing the response and output only necessary fields:

```
$data = $facebook->api('/me?fields=email','GET');
echo $data['email'];
```

PS: what are `echo "";` used for?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $user = $facebook->api('/me?fields=email','GET');
    echo $user['email'];

?>
```

You can learn much about PHP Arrays [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can just use this

```
<?php

    $user = $facebook->api('/me');
    echo $user['email'];

?>
```